# How to enable Identity_insert on SQL Server Level

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

In the article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4568653/fix-insert-exec-doesn-t-work-when-you-insert-row-containing-explicit-i
it said :

> INSERT EXEC doesn't work when you insert row containing explicit
> identity value into table with IDENTITY column and IDENTITY_INSERT is
> OFF by default in SQL Server

This means IDENTITY_INSERT can be set OFF by default in SQL Server and in the same manner ON.
Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: `so this means` - no, it was to mean "on the server side". As documented, identity insert can only be enabled for one table at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) confirms this:

> ## SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)
>
> Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column **of a table**.
>
> ...
>
> ### Remarks
>
> **At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.** If a table already has this property set to ON, and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table, SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.
>
> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value.
>
> The setting of SET IDENTITY_INSERT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.

**Emphasis mine**.

If you need to enable it on multiple tables, you must enable it on one table, disable it, then en able it on the next, etc, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that was also where I was going in my answer, but you've posted yours before I could complete mine, so.... +1

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable it for any table that you want to insert into like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tablename] ON
```

After you have completed the identity insert, you have to disable it

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tablename] OFF
```

After having disabled it you can enable it for another table

See here for [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)